# Copying cells to another workbook with sheets named on cell A1 of the MASTER

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with a "MASTER" sheet that is populated by the choice of a dropdown box in A1.  I need to copy some information from that "MASTER" sheet to another workbook "Summer Completion" in which the sheet names correspond with the drop down box. I have the macro written but I am having trouble getting it to see the sheet name based on what is in A1 of the MASTER sheet.  Where it is having trouble at is shtName.  I believe this will work if I can get past it not seeing the sheet name.

```
Sub Copy_With_AutoFilter()

Dim My_Range As Range
Dim wsMASTER As Worksheet
Dim shtName As Worksheet
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long
Dim FilterCriteria As String
Dim CCount As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wbSource As Workbook

'Set filter range on ActiveSheet
Set My_Range = Range("A94:E119")

'Set the sheet
Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
Set wsMASTER = wbSource.Worksheets("MASTER")
Set shtName = wbSource.Worksheets(wsMASTER.Range("A1").Value)

'Set the destination worksheet
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("A:\Accounting\Manifest Project\Manifest\2014\Completion Bonus\Summer Bonus\" & shtName & ".xlsx")

'Unprotect Sheet
If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
    My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
      MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
            vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
      Exit Sub
End If

'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, .....
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

'Firstly, remove the AutoFilter
My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

'Filter and set the filter field and the filter criteria
My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">0"

'Check if there are not more then 8192 areas
CCount = 0
On Error Resume Next
CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisisble).Areas(1).cells.Count
On Error GoTo 0
If CCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas:" _
         & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data.", _
           vbOKOnly, "Copy to worksheet"
Else
    'Copy the visible data and use PasteSpecial to paste to the Destsh
    With My_Range.Parent.AutoFilter.Range
        On Error Resume Next
        'Set rng to the visible cells in My_Range without the header row
        Set rng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count) _
                  .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            'Copy and paste the cells into DestSh below the existing data
            rng.Copy
            With wbTarget.Range("A" & LastRow(wbTarget) + 1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With
        End If
    End With
End If

'Close AutoFilter
My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
Application.Goto wbTarget.Range("A1")
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set shtName = wbSource.Worksheets(wsMASTER.Range("A1").Value)
```

Your question suggests that the sheet you want is in `wbTarget`, not `wbSource`...

Try this revision:

```
Dim sName as String

Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
Set wsMASTER = wbSource.Worksheets("MASTER")

Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("A:\Accounting\Manifest Project\Manifest\2014\" & _
                          "Completion Bonus\Summer Bonus\Completion Bonus.xlsx")

sName = wsMASTER.Range("A1").Value

On Error Resume Next
Set shtName = wbTarget.Worksheets(sName)
On Error Goto 0

If shtName is Nothing Then
    Msgbox "Sheet '" & sName "' was not found in target workbook!"
    Exit Sub
End If

'rest of code using shtName
```

Comment: The sheet I am copying to is in wbTarget, but the NAME of the sheet matches whatever is in the "A1" of the wbSource and changes when the dropdown box is changed.  That is what I am having trouble with in the code.  How do you tell it that, so it ends up on the proper sheet?

Comment: To add a little bit more about the problem, if I leave it as is I get a run time error 91 on that line.  If I change it to wbTarget I get a run time error 9 on that line.

Comment: Tryed it and now it is giving me a run time error 91 on Set wbTarget.  I am beginning to think that it is not possible to get it to find worksheets in another workbook based on a cell from the source workbook.

Comment: I beat my head over this all day.  I am taking a break and sleep on it.  Thanks for any ideas you may give me.

Comment: Looking at your code again, it doesn't really match your description of what you're trying to do.  What are you getting for the master sheet - is it the name of the file, or the name of the sheet?  You seem to be using the value for both of those....

Comment: The MASTER sheet is a sheet within a workbook. A1 is a dropdown box on that sheet and I want to have range A94:E119 copy over to another sheet that is of the same name as A1 (whatever is chosen from the dropdown box) in another workbook.  This new workbook is a consolidation of information so will be added to weekly.  I hope this explains it better.

Comment: What's the name of the second file?  Is it the same as the name of the worksheet in that file?  In your code you're attempting to do this: `With wbTarget.Range(...)` but `wbTarget` is a workbook, not a worksheet, so it doesn't have a `Range` property.

Comment: The source workbook is Tech Manifests with a sheet named MASTER. The target workbook is Completion Bonus with different sheets named same as cell A1 on MASTER. So I need the range to copy over from Tech Manifests>MASTER to Completion Bonus>(whatever is in MASTER "A1")

Comment: Edited again - see revision

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you.  That got me past my problem finding the sheet.  My code seems to have another problem, so I will post another question.